# Azure DevOps - Using a secure file to store secrets referenced by app.confg

Tags: azure-devops

Context

creating an sdk that uses AWS DynamoDb in .NET 4.7.2.  In my test project, I have an app.config file that references a secrets.confg file that stores my AWS keys.  The secrets config is not included in any commits, for obvious reasons.  However, I've uploaded secrets.config to my Library in DevOps as a "secure file".  I also have a "download config file" task in the build process that downloads secrets.config to Agent.Temporary

Issue

I don't understand how modify the build process to "pick up" my secrets.config file so that when running my tests, the test project's app.config file knows where to look for secrets.config.

I've looked over a lot of documentation and I can't find exactly how to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured this out by using a couple of tasks within the Build Configuration.

I added a Download Secure File task to download my app.config from the Library.  And then setup a Copy Files task for each project that needed the app.config.

Each task set:

1. Source Folder to "$(Agent.TempDirectory)"
2. Contents to "app.config"
3. Target folder to "$(Build.SourcesDirectory)\Project.Tests\"

In the end, it wasn't any more complicated than that.  I hope this will help others...